# Cannot find type parameter if it is an inner class of the subclass in Java

Tags: java

Why does the following code have a compile error:

Foo.java:

```
public abstract class Foo<T> {
    public abstract T getInner();
}
```

MyFoo.java:

```
public class MyFoo extends Foo<MyFooInner> {
    public static class MyFooInner {
    }
    public MyFooInner getInner() {
        return new MyFooInner();
    }
}
```

Compiling the second class results in:

```
MyFoo.java:1: cannot find symbol
symbol: class MyFooInner
public class MyFoo extends Foo<MyFooInner> {
                               ^
1 error
```

Is there a way around this problem besides putting the inner class in its own file?

Comment: This is an interesting question... I'm not sure the language allows it since Java Generics are implemented via type erasure. I would expect that you'll have to make MyFooInner a top-level class.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the following notation:

```
public class MyFoo extends Foo<MyFoo.MyFooInner> {...
```

**UPDATE**: Static nested classes are effectively a top level class as specified [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html):

> A static nested class interacts with the instance members of its outer
>   class (and other classes) just like any other top-level class. In
>   effect, a static nested class is behaviorally a top-level class that
>   has been nested in another top-level class for packaging convenience.

So, the only way you can refer to a static nested class is mentioning its parent class somewhere. Otherwise it is a reference to an imported class or to a class within the same package.

**UPDATE**: To explain it even more, another way to reference the class is to import it like this:

```
import my.package.MyFoo.MyFooinner;

public class MyFoo extends Foo<MyFooInner> {...
```

Comment: Can you also *explain* it? Or was it just a lucky wild guess?

Comment: That's the usual way you refer to static nested classes: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: @AndreyAdamovich - That's not exactly helpful.

Comment: @Kublai Khan, what exactly do you need?

Comment: Accordingly to oracle's linked tutorial, declaring the inner class without static modifier should allow you to us it as a generic type without explicitly mention the outer class.

Comment: @AndreyAdamovich - this is not explaining *why* the type needs to be qualified. Your update only says that static nested classes act like top level classes.

Comment: @KublaiKhan, yes, your answer is a bit more precise on explaing that, though the question was about the way to do it and not about explaining it :) thanks for the addition anyway

Comment: @AndreyAdamovich - Your updates made it clear +1, didn't mean to be a stickler :)

Answer (score 2):

To build on [@Andrey Adamovich's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575908/cannot-find-type-parameter-if-it-is-an-inner-class-of-the-subclass-in-java/7575952#7575952), the reason for this is that types identified in a class declaration must make sense to members outside that class. This is the same as if I had
written the following in another class file:

```
MyFooInner mfi = new MyFooInner()
```

This would not compile because that class wouldn't know what `MyFooInner` was - I would either need to qualify it by writing `MyFoo.MyFooInner` or else use `import MyPackage.MyFoo.MyFooInner;`. The same logic applies to class declarations.

For the same reason, nested classes that are declared `private` cannot be used in the parent class's declaration at all.